# GPS not stopping while app entered the background state

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, location, locationmanager

In my app a given area is watched using two GPS locations. The radius of the area is entered in a UITextField. When a value is entered in this field and the Start button is tapped the given area is watched. Even when the app entered the background state. When tapping the Stop button stopUpdatingLocation is called and the GPS arrow disappear when the app is dismissed. So far so good. BTW the background services is flagged TRUE in the plist file because the area has to be watched when the app is in the background too.

However when the user starts the app, don't enter a value in the textfield and dismiss the app the GPS arrow stays visible.

Is there a way to stop the GPS in the last case and keep it running when a value was entered in the textField? Can I use an if/else statement on pushing the home button?

Comment: @P.J. Thanks for your reply. I have tried that but (i think) because of using a mapView the location service start immediately when the app is loaded. Any suggestions how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Start your location service only when user enters value on textField / or better user taps on start button and not when your application starts.

For user entered into TextField:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that but (i think) because of using a mapView the location service start immediately when the app is loaded. Any suggestions how to achieve it?

Comment: your map view class is still in memory, remove it from memory. If you are using ARC, set your viewcontroller = nil, or better your mapView = nil, but remember, do this only when you have removed this view..

Comment: Thanks but this puzzles me. When I do this the GPS functionallity is imho always stopped when the app is transferred to the background. When a value is set in the textfield and the user has hit the start button (so the given area is watched) the app has to continue running in the background. Really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: So you need to set flag, if you set start button, then you dont need to do nil to controller i.e. your view, if start is not pressed then release i.e. set to nil. Hope it helps you..

Comment: I've tried several things all with lack of success but indeed I need to set a flag. If the textField (or, actually better) when the startbutton is tapped a BOOL has to be YES. Then when the app is dismissed the app has to stay running in the background. So, as far as I know, I do have to do something in my appDelegate.m file. I really don't know what and how to do it. I've tried to use [location stopUpdatingLocation] in the didEnterBackground method but it did not stop. After reading a lot of docs it is still not clear to me what to do. Will you be so kind to help me with some code.

Comment: when you set [location stopUpdatingLocation], also you need to set location=nil. Try with this and tell me if you gain success.

Comment: This code:[location stopUpdatingLocation]; location = nil; in the applicationWillresignactive and in the applicationDidEnterBackground but nothing has changed. Sorry.